# Cannot remount wheel after installing new brake pads

Tags: brakes, pads

Bike: electric bike company model s
Age of bike: approximately 5 years or 4
Brakes: Tektro Auriga
Brake pads: p20.11

Issue: replaced old pads with new pads but new pads won't fit over rotor disc as there is not enough room. I have not ever had my brakes bled, I have never removed rear tire. Old and new pads are both p20.11.

Fix: I will try pushing in pistons but outside of this, with the above in mind, any other ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 10):

When replacing the pads on (hydraulic) disc brakes, you first have to push back the pistons, as they are automatically adjusting for wear.

Be careful, some pistons are ceramic and can be damaged if mishandled. You can use a flat head screwdriver, but it's better to use something softer, like plastic tire levers. Or you push them back, while keeping the old pads in.

Comment: I'd like to suggest adding a nope about how to push them back and what tools to use (since OP obviously has no experience with that)

Comment: What I use for pushing back the ceramic pistons is use the handle of a Park Tool single-ended cone wrench. The handle is padded with rubber, and is just the right tool for pushing back the pistons.